# Ошибка неправильного синтаксиса около ON DUBLICATE

Tags: sql, sqlite

Использую SQLite. При запросе `INSERT INTO conversations (id,chiefs) VALUES (3,123) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE chiefs=123;` вылетает ошибка: `Ошибка при выполнении SQL запроса к базе данных 'db': near "DUPLICATE": syntax error`. Что не так, кто может подсказать?

Comment: В SQLite нет on duplicate. так что только отдельными запросами. сначала попытка insert, если вернет ошибку дублирования - то update

Comment: @Mike Может есть какой-то другой способ, внутри самого SQLite?

Comment: боюсь, что нет. гугл на "sqlite on duplicate" выдает разные способы, касающиеся конкретных ситуаций. но они все сводятся к нескольким запросам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться оним из следующих вариантов:

*[INSERT OR REPLACE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)*:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO conversations (id,chiefs) VALUES (3,123);
```

---

*[UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html)* (добавлено в версии SQLite 3.24.0 (2018-06-04)):

```
sqlite> .mode column
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> create table conversations (id int primary key,chiefs int);
sqlite> insert into conversations (id,chiefs) VALUES (3,111);
sqlite> INSERT INTO conversations (id,chiefs) VALUES (3,123) ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET chiefs=123;
sqlite> select * from conversations;
id          chiefs
----------  ----------
3           123
```

---

*[ON CONFLICT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)*:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE conversations (id INT PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT REPLACE, chiefs int);
sqlite> INSERT INTO conversations (id,chiefs) VALUES (3,100);
sqlite> INSERT INTO conversations (id,chiefs) VALUES (3,123);
sqlite> select * from conversations;
id          chiefs
----------  ----------
3           123
```

Comment: Не самый лучший для меня вариант, сделал вариант из комментариев, все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Для меня подошел именно вариант: сначала попытаться выполнить `INSERT`, если вернет ошибку дублирования - то выполнить `UPDATE`. Спасибо, @Mike!

Comment: Интересно чем вам `ON CONFLICT` не подошел? Он делает тоже самое, но одной командой...

Comment: @MaxU, к тому времени не было Вашего ответа и я не знал про этот способ. Спасибо за предложение, обязательно попробую.